# Flex sdk integration with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, sdk, ide, mxml

I have the following version of eclipse

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857
```

And i have downloaded flex_sdk 4.6.My question is that how do i add this plugin for the eclipse in order to use it for flash development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK is a development kit, not an IDE.

Though you can use the mxmlc + compc compilers for free, you will not have code hinting, code completion, ...

If you need all that, you will need to buy and download the full [Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html) package.
Or you can just download the trial first.

Then you will be able to install the Plugin into eclipse.

Follow the instructions in the release note to install as an eclipse plugin into an existing eclipse instance:
http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/release-note/flash-builder-4-6-release.html